# Send current view to ViewModel using DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a `BindingAdapter` like

```
@BindingAdapter({ "onGlobalLayout" })
public static void setOnGlobalLayout(View view, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener) {
    ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
}
```

In XML I have a `View` like

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewId"
        bind:onGlobalLayout="@{viewModel.onLayoutListener}"
        />
```

In ViewModel I have

```
public ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onLayoutListener(View view){
        return new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                 // get x,y,width, height of view           
            }
        };
}
```

Now I want to send the current `View` to `ViewModel` so I add a parametter `View view` to `onLayoutListener` but in XML I don't know how to send it.
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

**UPDATE**
Thank @pskink for suggest a better way for checking layout change. 
With `android:onLayoutChange` I don't need `BindingAdapter`

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/viewId"
     android:onLayoutChange="@{viewModel.onLayoutListener(viewId)}"
/>
```

Java

```
public View.OnLayoutChangeListener onLayoutUpdateWeightSuccessfulListener(final View v) {
        return new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                    int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                    // left, top
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: use `android:onLayoutChange`

Comment: @pskink does `android:onLayoutChange` work same as `OnGlobalLayoutListener` or which one is better? in first look, I see if I use `android:onLayoutChange` my code is shorter

Comment: it is built-in adapter so you dont have to add any `@BindingAdapter`, just use it and pass `View.OnLayoutChangeListener` object

Comment: @PhanVanLinh please post your code if it is possible directly with `android:onLayoutChange` , so that it can be helpful to others also.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/data-binding/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/ViewBindingAdapter.java#194

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I have update the way using `android:onLayoutChange` in my question. Thank @pskink again for suggest a better way

Comment: @PhanVanLinh great, thanks a lot

Comment: just use `android:onLayoutChange="@{viewModel.myLayoutChange}"` and *public void myLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                    int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                    // left, top
            }*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply pass your `View` id, it should work

```
bind:onGlobalLayout="@{viewModel.onLayoutListener(viewId)}"
```

Comment: `bind:onGlobalLayout="@{(view) -> viewModel.onLayoutListener(view)}" should work, but I don't think a ViewModel should be dealing with layouts and views.